# QtQuick rendering error on Android

Tags: android, qt, ant, render, qml

I'm currently playing around with the demo QML apps from Qt5.2. Running them on my acer iconia 500 (Android4.0) works fine but when I run them on the Nexus 10 (Android 4.2) the whole scene is broken. Elements are not drawn, strange flickering and so on.
Apps based on widgets work fine on both devices.
My toolchain:

- apache-ant-1.9.3
- Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
- latest ndk

I get following warnings on both devices:

> WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
>   W/dalvikvm(21829): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNativeInputConnection'
>   W/dalvikvm(21829): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtExtractedText'

Additionaly on the Acer (which is working) I get:

> W/Qt      ( 2258): scenegraph\qsgcontext.cpp:440 (virtual void QSGRenderContext::initialize(QOpenGLContext*)): QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors

The only major difference I can see is that the acer uses "libEGL_tegra.so" and the Nexus the "libGLES_mali.so"

Any idea on this? Is there a missing renderflag?

thanks,
patrik

Comment: Can you provide more context? Missing stencil buffer would result no complex clipping, but the issue would not look like this then.

Comment: Hi Laszlo. The funny is like I wrote the error appears on my Acer but there everything seems to work. Its the Nexus which is not working. But there I get no special error.